# Using heremaps MapRoute API, is it possible to draw dotted line as route on map?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I would like to use dotted line to draw route on map using heremaps

Using Maproute API in heremaps, colour of the route can be changed. 
how about the route ? is dotted line possible to be drawn ?
Can I customise it ?

Also what is the usage of setRenderType() in Maproute API

what to do for drawing dotted line as route ?

dotted line is expected to be drawn as route on the map

Answer (score 0):

Currently, our Mobile SDKs do not expose a public API to change route style to dotted lines. Our development team is discussing whether to add this as a new feature. So please keep checking our next releases.